# How can I send a file (doc) to a mail as reply

Tags: 8.1, outlook, attachments, email

I got a mail from someone, now I need to send a file (doc or xls file) in reply to that mail. I am not able to attach anything other than photos. 
Is there any way to do this.

I can send doc file as attachment, if I try to share doc file from files apps. But it creates new thread of mail. But cant do as reply to some mail.

This is very basic feature. I don't think I am expecting anything weird.

Answer (score 6):

**Windows phone 8.1 does not support this feature**. Hence if you are using WP8.1 there is no way to attach a document in a reply. Only photos are supported.

The only way to send a document via mail is to share it from Files app or from Office. But as you said it will create a new thread.

With **Windows10-Mobile** it is now **possible to attach a document** in a reply.

Comment: Might be worth noting that with Windows 10 Mobile, you can now attach documents to a reply...

Comment: @RowlandShaw Thank for the info. I didn't know that.

Comment: Yes, I have updated to W10M. Now mail client is really powerful with many more features.